# Can I avoid overriding a method in the following scenario?

Tags: c#, interface

Let say there are 5 car rental agencies and when a person make's a rental online, XML with the car rental details is sent to the rental agencies where it will be parsed by the some software and will be input into their system.

Now, if there is a standard way to send XML for a car rental, then this is easy, but let's assume that each agency is partnered with a different interface for sending car rentals and each interface sends XML in a different format, so when it needs to be parsed, you can't have one standard method, you need to be able to override the method to handle multiple interfaces.  As an example,  you might have the following 2:

```
<Rental>
<FirstName>John</FirstName>
<LastName>Doe</LastName>
<Pickup time="13:00"/>
<Date>06/06/12</Date>
</Rental>
```

VS

```
<Rental>
<Name>
<First>John</First>
<Last>Doe</Last>
</Name>
<Pickup time="13:00" date="06/06/12"/>
</Rental>
```

If each car agency uses a different interface to process rentals, is the only approach to overwrite a method 5 times and with each new agency, it would have to grow again or is there a simpler approach to this?

Comment: You may want to consider using XSLT to transform the XML to and from some standard format.  You can use an XslCompiledTransform object to apply an XSLT script to any XML document and have it output the transformed XML document.  You can do it with files or all in memory.

Comment: Having a common interface for a Rental with an implementation for each variation seems like a fairly standard and reasonable way to approach this.

Comment: @SteveDog - I have seen XSLT, but it looks a little intimidating.

Comment: @Xaisoft I understand, I felt the same way at first and didn't want to learn it.  But I was forced to for a project I was assigned and after a couple days of working in it, I became quite pleased with it.  I'm by no means an expert in it, but it really doesn't take too much understanding to do simple transformations like what you are describing.  I'd recommend a good book on XSLT, but unfortunately I've never found one that wasn't dreadful!

Comment: With XSLT, would I be required to write a different XSLT file for each interface that requires the xml formatted in a special way?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good case for using the [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). Assuming you are doing OOP you can have a base object that provides the data for the car rental then wrap it (or decorate it) with another object that formats the data properly. You would need to make a seperate decorator for each of the various car rental agencies.

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you have to do for a new agency is to handle parsing of data into internal data presentation then by all means VERY WELL DONE ;). Why bother with something that seems very well suited to be separated business wise?

I guess you can solve it in numerous ways though if you really wanted. I would play around with the idea of creating an ai or ann for matching input towards best fit. but any solution would probably be way, way, WAY more expensive than just implementing the unique "parseCustomersData" function.